# Can not add subtitle to List item inside ForEach in Swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a simple list of cities in Swift UI and I need a List item to contain two rows: title and subtitle.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Cities - \(arrayDisplayedCount) results")) {

                if self.searchTerm.isEmpty {
                    List {
                        ForEach(range, id: \.self) {
                            VStack {
                                Text("Header \($0.name)").fontWeight(.bold)
                                Text("Subheader").fontWeight(.regular)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code compiles if I remove the VStack and second Text, in this way it doesn't compile. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the full test code I'm using:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Cities - some arrayDisplayedCount results")) {
                if true {
                    List {
                        ForEach(0..<3, id: \.self) { x in
                         //   Text("\($0)")  // if you only have this, great no need for "x in"
                            VStack {  // because you have this VStack, you need "x in" and you cannot use $0
                                Text("\(x)")
                                Text("Header").fontWeight(.bold)
                                Text("Subheader").fontWeight(.regular)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thank you, indeed this was an issue. Strange that compiler didn't give any reasonable comment, but instead showed somth else as if it was failing, some unrelated bool.

Comment: glad it worked. In my experience the compiler with SwiftUI often give you completely meaningless comments and error locations.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
ForEach(range, id: \.self) { _ in
...
}
```

Comment: this is not needed, since I use $0 as an item inside ForEach (I omitted it for simplicity)

Comment: have you tried it? Your code will not work/compile without the "_ in". Let me know if this does (does not) fix your problem.

Comment: yes I did try it, it doesn't help. Also inside ForEach closure you can ommit _in since you are going to use the $0 notation.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 11.4, compiling for ios 13.4 and macos (10.15.4) using the catalyst option. Your code does not compile without the "_ in".